# Using a widget for aggregate value in Django Admin

Tags: python, django

In my ModelAdmin, I have calculate two aggregate values and want to display those with a widget.

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(QuizAdmin, self).get_queryset(request).annotate(
            avg_difficulty=Avg('ratings__difficulty'),
            avg_rating=Avg('ratings__rating'),
        )
        return qs.filter(author__agents=request.user)
```

At the moment I'm doing this

```
def avg_difficulty(self, obj):
        return StarRatingWidget().render(attrs={'id': 'id_avg_difficulty'},name="avg_difficulty", value=obj.avg_difficulty, readonly=True)
```

Is there a simpler and more flexible way to use a widget for an aggregate value? Registering in the ModelForm does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the right way to do it, however, if your widget is only used for this case, you don't even need a widget. For instance, you could do:

```
from django.utils.html import format_html

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    readonly_fields = ['avg_difficulty']

    def avg_difficulty(self, obj):
        return format_html(
            ('<span id="id_avg_difficulty" class="rater" '
             'data-value="{}"></span>'), obj.avg_difficulty)
    avg_difficulty.short_description = "Average difficulty"
```

Comment: I want to use the widget multiple times, both as an input and as a read-only widget. I have the added problem that I want to use it for list items in the admin, but if I do that, the resources in the Media class are not loaded. Do you have any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: You can add a Media class to a ModelAdmin as well: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-asset-definitions